# How Acess Document Snapshot elements?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am accessing a document from firebase using the command `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Collection").doc(a).get();`
Can I accesses the elements without knowing their name and only by index number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DocumentSnapshot response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Collection").doc(a).get();
```

Will return a `DocumentSnapshot` object.

To access this object, which is returned in the form of a `Map<String, dynamic>`, you need to call `data()` on it, i.e:

```
Map<String, dynamic> resultsMap = response.data();
```

After this, it's basic Map manipulation. If you don't know the keys of this map, you can map your `map` into a `List`, and use the indexes then.

Incase you are wondering how to turn a map to a list,

```
List newList = resultsMap.entries.map((e) =>  e.value).toList();
print(newList[0]); //should print the value of what you need.
```

Comment: Thank you sir this saved me a huge number of document reads.